# Set due date to specific day and time in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, formula

Good day,
I am trying to create a regular excel formula that will check if a request is created on **"THURSDAY"** after **"6PM"**, then the **DUE DATE** will be the coming **"SATURDAY"** at **"12PM"**.
so far i am able to set the DUE DATE to SATURDAY, but no luck with setting the time to 12PM.
This is my formula:

`=IF(AND([@[DAY CREATED]]="Thu",[@[TIME CREATED]]>--("6:00 PM")),[@Created]+7-WEEKDAY([@Created]),[@[DUE DATE]])`

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Additional note: DAY CREATED has both a date and time which in this condition would usually be on a thursday between 6pm and 11:59pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can represent the time as a fraction of a day so if you add 0.5 to your date it should set the time to 12pm.  The cell will need to be formatted to show the date and time. I've not had time to test this so let me know if I'm totally wrong.

```
=IF(AND([@[DAY CREATED]]="Thu",[@[TIME CREATED]]>--("6:00 PM")),[@Created]+7-WEEKDAY([@Created])+0.5,[@[DUE DATE]])
```

You can use timevalue to reset the time before adding the 0.5

```
=IF(AND([@[DAY CREATED]]="Thu",[@[TIME CREATED]]>--("6:00 PM")),[@Created]+7-WEEKDAY([@Created])-mod([@Created],1)+0.5,[@[DUE DATE]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only issue is that the day created has a time and adding a 0.5 would add 12 hours to the time it was created. For example if the day created is on thursday at 7pm then with this formula i would get the result as sunday 7AM. I hope this clarifies :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. It would be useful if you were able to record the date separate from the time like you have done with the day.

Comment: Okay trying this out. getting the #VALUE error mainly due to the Timevalue formula. Trying to fix and will let you know if it works. Thank you very much

Comment: Another update. Try using mod(created,1) that gets the fraction of the date value which represents the time.

Comment: Brilliant. Works perfectly :) thank you very much for your help. Saved me hours of research / trial and error / etc... Appreciated

Comment: You're very welcome. I learnt something new in the process :).